# Any difference between httpd and apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

Snow Leopard calls it httpd and Ubuntu apache2. Are there any differences? One difference is apache2ctl on Ubuntu and apachectl on Snow Leopard.

thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, httpd is basically just the same as apache2 in most modern operating systems. Of course, you should check an actual version of Apache in your system because minor version numbers can (and will) differ.

Comment: It's not so much about "modern" vs. "non-modern", but rather just historical naming conventions. RHEL6, for instance, still calls apache "httpd".

Comment: @ErikA I meant there still could be Apache 1.X somewhere also referred as httpd. But in all recent OSes httpd is Apache 2.X not Apache 1.X.

Comment: Ahh, sure. Understood now.

Answer (score 4):

On Snow Leopard, I see this:

```
$ apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix)
Server built:   Dec  1 2010 09:58:15
```

On Lucid, I see this:

```
$ apache2ctl -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Sep  1 2011 09:47:45
```

So, yes, essentially the same.  The difference in naming probably has to do with historic packaging conventions at Ubuntu and Apple.  RHEL, for what it's worth, also calls its Apache2 package "httpd".

Comment: The best solution, given that we don't know your patchlevel or versions you're comparing, is just what @cjc did. Check the versions. And you might want to see if you can find the compiled options as well. Otherwise, we'd have to know what in particular you're trying to do to see what difference you're worried about between them.

Comment: thx - I'm trying to keep local dev and prod in sync as much as possible as our SA has bailed out. Ideally, I'd like to know if I could just create a symlink and have a common set of scripts to check for.